# Metacity used with proprietary driver and proposed repository

Tags: compiz, nvidia

I enabled the proposed repository in a fresh install with the proprietary `nvidia-173` driver. After the reboot, I noticed that minimizing and maximizing, there were none of the expected effect (using Ubuntu Classic, even with proprietary driver, Unity does not work - another issue). Furthermore I confirmed by trying to switch workspaces using keyboard shortcuts, and the square desktop wall was replaced by horizontally lined workspaces of Metacity.

Of course, the upgraded Compiz could be responsible, but I can't figure out what to do - please advice. Additionally, if it's an issue with the softwares from proposed repo, how and what do I do to notify the developers of the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start the 'Additional Drivers' application do you see that the 173 driver is activated and in use?  The image below shows the Nvidia graphics driver as being activated, but not in use.

[image]

Let's assume that your video driver is installed and functioning correctly, are you suggesting in your question that you want to switch from Metacity to Compiz?  If this is the case, have you tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> with the following command:

```
compiz --replace
```

To check if everything is up to snuff to run Compiz, I will use the code [here](http://codepad.org/4m73Tn9W).  Please let me know if I have misunderstood what you are asking.

Comment: Yes it is activated. (Sorry for late reply but for some reason, I am not being notified of anything) Compiz used to work with my fresh install and proprietary driver, but after upgrading from proposed repo, Metacity is use. I'll use that command now, dunno why I didn't that of that.

Comment: ... The command did the trick... seriously, I'm an idiot.

Comment: I would expect that we all miss the little things from time to time.  Glad to read that it worked for you. :D