# Set compositing manager preference to Compiz

Tags: compiz, metacity

As I discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50047/metacity-used-with-proprietary-driver-and-proposed-repository/50124#50124), for some reason, Metacity was used instead of Compiz even with capable GPU and driver. I want to set the preference to use Conmpiz wherever possible, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you might want to try...from a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ATL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions
sudo gedit classic-gnome.session
```

Find the line listed as `Required-windowmanager=gnome-wm`

and change it to `Required-windowmanager=compiz`

This is something I had done in versions earlier than Ubuntu 11.04.  I do not recall having to change anything else to get compiz to replace Metacity by default.