# Which entry in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions corresponds to what?

Tags: gnome-session

Related to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50676/set-compositing-manager-preference-to-compiz/50691#50691).

```
:/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions$ ls
2d-gnome.session   classic-gnome.session  ubuntu.session
2d-ubuntu.session  gnome.session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `2d-gnome.session` Failsafe GNOME
- `classic-gnome.session`Classic GNOME
- `ubuntu.session` Ubuntu (regular Unity)
- `2d-ubuntu.session` Unity 2D
- `gnome.session`GNOME